# How to access parent site products in child site using drupal services ?

Tags: commerce, ubercart, services

I want to create shopping cart in child sites but using PARENT site database.
I don't want to install UberCart for each child site as i have several child sites.

For example : when i add a product (LAPTOP) it must be available on all child sites with complete detail (Title,Model,Price,sku,etc.....)

Can someone guide me to right path.
Using drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set up different codes connecting to same database.

So all sites might have different CSS but same database so same products and other Drupal configuration.

Essentially it is one Drupal site. Does this solve your problem?